# How to retrieve unconverted data from xml file

Tags: powershell

We have a script that does a backup of NTFS permissions to an `.xml` file:

```
Get-Acl -Path 'C:\myFolder' | Export-Clixml -Path $ntfsXmlFile
```

Then on another machine we try to restore these permissions on a specific folder. This would be easy by doing

```
Import-Clixml -LiteralPath $ntfsXmlFile | Set-Acl -Path 'C:\otherFolder'
```

However, in some cases it can be that not all accounts in the $ntfsXmlFile are available on the second machine. So we create the Access Control List manually and verify if each Access Control Entry exists before adding it to the ACL.

The problem is that unknown account names are converted to an unrecognizable string when using `Import-Clixml`:

```
BinaryLength AccountDomainSid               Value
------------ ----------------               -----
          28 S-1-5-21-497061539-31097515    S-1-5-21-497061539-31067-310415-1030
```

The xml file exported by `Export-Clixml` looks like this:

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity</T>
      <T>System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity</T>
      <T>System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity</T>
      <T>System.Security.AccessControl.CommonObjectSecurity</T>
      <T>System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <ToString>System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity</ToString>
    <Props>
      <S N="AccessRightType">System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights</S>
      <S N="AccessRuleType">System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule</S>
      <S N="AuditRuleType">System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule</S>
      <B N="AreAccessRulesProtected">true</B>
      <B N="AreAuditRulesProtected">false</B>
      <B N="AreAccessRulesCanonical">true</B>
      <B N="AreAuditRulesCanonical">true</B>
    </Props>
    <MS>
      <S N="PSPath">Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\myFolder</S>
      <S N="PSParentPath">Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\myFolder</S>
      <S N="PSChildName">B</S>
      <Obj N="PSDrive" RefId="1">
        <TN RefId="1">
          <T>System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <ToString>C</ToString>
        <Props>
          <S N="CurrentLocation"></S>
          <S N="Name">C</S>
          <Obj N="Provider" RefId="2">
            <S>Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem</S>
          </Obj>
          <S N="Root">C:\</S>
          <S N="Description">System</S>
          <Nil N="MaximumSize" />
          <Obj N="Credential" RefId="3">
            <TN RefId="2">
              <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</T>
              <T>System.Object</T>
            </TN>
            <ToString>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</ToString>
            <Props>
              <Nil N="UserName" />
              <Nil N="Password" />
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Nil N="DisplayRoot" />
        </Props>
        <MS>
          <U64 N="Used">70907654144</U64>
          <U64 N="Free">14884746544</U64>
        </MS>
      </Obj>
      <Obj N="PSProvider" RefId="4">
        <TN RefId="3">
          <T>System.Management.Automation.ProviderInfo</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <ToString>Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem</ToString>
        <Props>
          <S N="ImplementingType">Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider</S>
          <S N="HelpFile">System.Management.Automation.dll-Help.xml</S>
          <S N="Name">FileSystem</S>
          <S N="PSSnapIn">Microsoft.PowerShell.Core</S>
          <S N="ModuleName">Microsoft.PowerShell.Core</S>
          <Nil N="Module" />
          <S N="Description"></S>
          <S N="Capabilities">Filter, ShouldProcess, Credentials</S>
          <S N="Home">C:\Users\bob</S>
          <Obj N="Drives" RefId="5">
            <TN RefId="4">
              <T>System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo, System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]</T>
              <T>System.Object</T>
            </TN>
            <LST>
              <S>A</S>
              <Ref RefId="1" />
              <S>D</S>
              <Obj RefId="6">
                <S>L</S>
              </Obj>
              <S>S</S>
              <Obj RefId="7">
                <S>T</S>
              </Obj>
              <S>TestDrive</S>
              <S>Z</S>
            </LST>
          </Obj>
        </Props>
      </Obj>
      <Nil N="CentralAccessPolicyId" />
      <Nil N="CentralAccessPolicyName" />
      <S N="Path">Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\myFolder</S>
      <S N="Owner">BUILTIN\Administrators</S>
      <S N="Group">GROUPHC\Domain Users</S>
      <Obj N="Access" RefId="8">
        <TN RefId="5">
          <T>System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection</T>
          <T>System.Collections.ReadOnlyCollectionBase</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <IE>
          <S>System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule</S>
          <S>System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule</S>
          <S>System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule</S>
        </IE>
      </Obj>
      <S N="Sddl">O:BAG:DUD:PAI(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-497061539-3109733767-3104415515-1037)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-497061539-3109733767-3104415515-1038)</S>
      <S N="AccessToString">BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl_x000A_PC1\TestUser1 Allow  Modify, Synchronize_x000A_PC1\TestUser2 Allow  Modify, Synchronize</S>
      <S N="AuditToString"></S>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

We're trying to access the property `Access` but the following fails:

```
$rawXml = [Xml] (Get-Content -LiteralPath $ntfsFile)
$rawXml.SelectNodes('Objs.Obj.MS.Obj.N.Access')
```

Ideally we would like to retrieve the following:

```
BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl_x000A_
PC1\TestUser1 Allow  Modify, Synchronize_x000A_
PC1\TestUser2 Allow  Modify, Synchronize
```

Is there a way to get the correct account principal name out of the exported xml file?

Comment: CliXml is still just XML - so read it the same way you would any other XML document :-)

Comment: Thank you, I tried to do something like this `$rawXml = [Xml] (Get-Content -Path $ntfsXmlFile)` but I can't seem to be able to access the properties with `$rawXml.Objs.Obj` or `Select-Xml -Xml $rawXml -XPath "//Objs:Obj"`

Comment: `$rawxml.Objs.Obj.MS.S |? N -eq Owner |% InnerText` seems to work just fine (WPS 5.1 on Win10)

Comment: Thank you Mathias, yes it works for `Owner` but not for the array `Access`. I've updated the OP to be more clear.

Comment: We got it now, thanks for your help `($rawxml.Objs.Obj.MS.S |? N -eq AccessToString |% InnerText ) -split '_x000A_'`.

Comment: @DarkLite1, please add your answer. It will be helpful for others in future

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Mathias in the comments the following code works to retrieve the Access list:

```
$rawXml = [Xml] (Get-Content -Path $ntfsFile)

($rawXml.Objs.Obj.MS.S | Where-Object N -EQ AccessToString | 
ForEach-Object InnerText ) -split '_x000A_'
```